# NuPlayer seems to freeze MediaPlayer on Samsung devices, how to disable programmatically?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, samsung-mobile

I've been banging my head on the wall for a few days now with `MediaPlayer`. After many hours of deliberation I decided to check the video player on lollipop devices and it is `NuPlayer`. Currently I have a `RecyclerView` of Video objects that all use a `MediaPlayer` what is frustrating is that on a Samsung S6 device the UI will lock up and freeze after scrolling down or up a list.

My hunch was that it was having issues preparing and recycling the `MediaPlayer` object. After trying out everything programmatically to solve the issue what really seems to resolve it is is disabling `NuPlayer` in the developer settings, when using `AwesomePlayer` everything works fine, albeit just a little slower.

Is there any way to disable `NuPlayer` programmatically on specific devices?

Comment: I am looking for a way to use AwesomePlayer instead of NuPlayer as well. Have you found any way of telling MediaPlayer to use it or prefer it instead?

Comment: @AndyRoid were you able to resolve it?